# why scikit-learn StandardScaler doesnt support keep_nan operation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when I want to do machine learning project, i want to scale my input into (0,1)

I use sklearn function to do that, such as StandScaler()
but i found once my data contains nan, fit_transform() will fail, as following:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

but i think there is some kind of need, wants to keep nan, and do standard scale in other not nan data.

why sklearn dont support that? Is there any methods to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you are using an old (i.e. before 0.20) version of scikit-learn. This issue was indeed resolved in v0.20; from the [change log](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.20.html#id37):

> **Major Feature**: NaN values are ignored and handled in the following preprocessing methods: `preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler, preprocessing.MinMaxScaler, preprocessing.RobustScaler, preprocessing.StandardScaler, preprocessing.PowerTransformer, preprocessing.QuantileTransformer classes and preprocessing.maxabs_scale, preprocessing.minmax_scale, preprocessing.robust_scale, preprocessing.scale, preprocessing.power_transform, preprocessing.quantile_transform functions`

See also the closed Github issue [#10404](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10404) and the respective merged pull request [#11206](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/11206).

So, just upgrade your scikit-learn to a recent version, and you should be fine, i.e. NaN values will indeed be ignored during such preprocessing.